# Add a method to a prototype that returns in all caps

Tags: javascript

I am writing code for a assignment but the code i write turns out "syntax error" unexpected '' in repl.it even when getting a console.log to output expected answers the code doesn't read as true and shows code as finished

I've tried creating new variables and syncing them to this and return but the code doesn't read as true

this is what's expected "Add a method to the Person's prototype called "shoutName" that returns the person's name in all uppercase letters."
this is what returns

```js
function Person(name) {
    this.name = name;
    this.shoutName = function() {
        name.toUpperCase();
        return.this.name.toUpperCase();
    }
}

/* Do not modify code below this line */

const john = new Person('John');
console.log(john.shoutName(), '<-- should be "JOHN"');
```

Comment: `reurn.this...` do you mean `return this...` ?

Comment: Can you post a complete snippet please? Looks like you are missing the first line.

Comment: I see a couple of issues with your code. Syntax is wrong with return. Second is your this.

Comment: Actually, your error says **`"Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ."`** Do you see that there is a period after `token`? That's the unexpected character. Work through syntax errors before posting. Voting to close.

Answer (score 0):

You should remove `.` after `return`. And also you are not adding the method to `prototype` you are adding method to the object itself.You should add method to `Person.prototype`

```js
function Person(name){
    this.name = name;
}
Person.prototype.shoutName = function() {
   return this.name.toUpperCase();
}
/* Do not modify code below this line */
const john = new Person('John');
console.log(john.shoutName(), '<-- should be "JOHN"');
```

Answer (score 0):

You should have have a space between the `return` keyword and the value you want to return, not a dot, which causes a `SyntaxError`. Also, you should add the `shoutName` method to `Person`'s prototype instead of each Person object that is created, for better maintainability.

```js
function Person(name) {
    this.name = name;
}
Person.prototype = {
  /*add any methods you want all Person objects to have*/
  shoutName: function(){
    return this.name.toUpperCase();
  }
};

const john = new Person('John');
console.log(john.shoutName(), '<-- should be "JOHN"');
```